# TypeScript Compiler doesn't delete files I deleted

Tags: javascript

Folders and files I deleted in my TypeScript codes are not deleted by TypeScript Compiler. I shared the folder structure of my project below. Pay attention to the `src/events` folder and the`dist/events` folder. The files I deleted are still there.

Project Structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: I can't say about this compiler in particular, but it's not unusual for compilers to leave existing files in the destination folder. I usually just delete the content of that folder to make sure there are no leftovers when deleting or renaming files.

Comment: This is by design.